# Need to understand the SMS lately sent by ITDEPT - 'Total tax by Employer for Q is xxxx......'

Tags: income-tax, india, income

Total TDS by Employer for Qtr ending Dec 31 is Rs. XXXXX and cumulative TDS for FY 18-19 is Rs. YYYYY. View 26AS for details.

YYYYY is way greater than XXXXX , could someone tell me how to interpret this, meanwhile I m trying to find 26AS form.

Answer (score 1):

This text is sent by the Income Tax Department stating your employer has deposited tax on your behalf.

YYYYY is the amount of tax for your financial year, ie from April 2018-March 2019, whereas MMMMM is the amount for quarter Oct 2018-Dec 2018.

Thus YYYY would be greater than MMMM.

Refer [this](https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/personal-finance/how-to-view-download-your-form-26as-and-why-it-is-important-2533847.html) to check Form 26 AS.